# iOS Codesign error when developing on remote mac

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

I rented a development mac from macincloud.com so obviously, I do not have a admin password.

So now Im finished with the app coding and added the necessary provisioning profiles. But when archiving I get the error

codesign failed with exit code 1

But in Xcode it shows me that the provisioning profiles are ok:

[image]

As you can see the provisioning is ok. But I suspect the main problem is not having admin password, since it asked me several times when accessing keychain.

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your Xcode is showing you have the right credentials to code sign your app.  But your distribution certificate is in the keychain.  When you archive, it needs to be able to read that certificate.  So if it's asking you for the admin password so it can read from the keychain, and you're canceling it out, it can't finish code signing.

Comment: thanks...does that mean that a mac without admin pass is useless in this case? I use a remote desktop to connect to a rented mac (macincloud.com)

Comment: Seems like there's several articles online about people trying to do iOS builds with the macincloud service.  I've never used it.  I'd contact their support and explain what you're trying to do and your blockers.